# Vitali Theorem Proof

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In the proof of Vitali's theorem the Vitali set is constructed. After the construction another set is created, namely $V_{k}=V+q_{k}=\{v+q_{k}:v\in V\}$ where $V$ ist the Vitali set and $q_k\in[0,1]$ are all the rational numbers in $[0,1]$.

Would it not be enough to just use the modulo group from which the Vitali set was created? Why is this additional step of creating $V_k$ necessary?

Comment: What do you mean by enough? Do you have a different argument without using these shifts of $V$?

Comment: It should work exactly the same. The shifts occur when building the modulo group anyways.

Comment: So, to me it seems you're saying that these things pop up anyway. Here, you just have them explicitly written down. I'd guess that they are used in most arguments for the non-measurability of the Vitali set, in a more or less obvious way. The point is, that you want a countable number of sets, which cover the whole interval, and so that if one set is measurable, all of them are, and they have the same measure (and the easiest way to get there is to use these shifts).

Comment: Ok, maybe there is not even more to it, than I was confused with him writing it down explicitly. Can an OP delete this?